# I want react-responsive-carousel to be continuous in the same direction always, and not return in the opposite direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-responsive-carousel, I want it to be continuous towards the same direction, and not return towards the opposite direction. anyone Help me?

```
<Carousel onClickItem={handleItemClick}
  className={`promos-slider ${styles['slider']} ${(copy ? styles['copy'] : '')}`}
  showThumbs={false} infiniteLoop emulateTouch interval={5000}
  showArrows={false} showStatus={false} showIndicators={!!imagesSlider} autoPlay >
  {
    (promos) && promos?.map(({ label, code, images }, key) => {
      
      if (imagesSlider && (!images || !images.length || images.length < 1)) return null;
      
      return (<div className={`${styles['item']}`} key={key}>
          {
            !imagesSlider ?
            <div className={styles['promo']}>
              <div className={styles['title']}>{label}</div>
              <div className={styles['code']} id={id + '-' + key}>{t('Code')}: <span>{code}</span></div>
              <div className={styles['legal']}>{t("ApplyCodeToCart")}</div>
            </div>
              :
              <img src={images[0]} alt="" />
          }
        </div>
      )})
  }
</Carousel>
```